Customize options of page size select component embedded inside pagination component in ant design reactjs
There is a select component embedded inside Pagination component for changing pageSize. I want to customize the options label in this select box so I can have my numbers in other languages.

This is possible in a standalone Select component by defining options like this:
options = {[
  { value: "10", label: <span>10 in another language</span> },
  { value: "20", label: <span>20 in another language</span> },
]}

Though I couldn't find a way to override these options in Pagination.
I tried setting locale property, but it only changes  / page label. I want to change the number itself.
locale: { items_per_page: "label to replace [/ page] label" }

I also tried setting pageSizeOptions, but the problem is I can only assign arrays of strings or numbers to it. It wouldn't take objects with label and value keys like the Select component.
And using strings like below causes generating a NaN for pageSize:
<Pagination
  //This is not possible:
  pageSizeOptions={[
    {
      label: formatNumbers("10", lng) as string,
      value: 10,
    },
    {
      label: formatNumbers("20", lng) as string,
      value: 20,
    }
  ]}
  //This is what it accepts, but will cause error:
  pageSizeOptions={[
    formatNumbers("10", lng) as string,
    formatNumbers("20", lng) as string,
  ]}
  onShowSizeChange={(current, size) => {
    console.log(size); // returns NaN
  }}
  defaultCurrent={1}
  total={100}
/>


It's not possible to have different label and value but you can create a feature request issue in antd github
